# Found a relation regarding the primes, is this interesting?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization, pi

Define $S_{odd}$ as all $n\in N $ where $n$ is the product of an odd number of distinct primes. Define $S_{even}$ similarly. Thus:
$$S_{odd} = \{2,3,5,...,30,42,....\}$$

$$S_{even} = \{6,10,14, ....,210,...\}$$

To be clear, neither contains a multiple of a square

Then:
$$\sum_{s\in S_{odd}} 1/s^2 - \sum_{s\in S_{even}} 1/s^2 = 1 - 6/\pi^2$$
I think we can maybe write the left hand-side in terms of $\sum_{p\in P} 1/p^k$, but it's a bit of a puzzle. What are you thoughts?

Comment: This follows quickly from standard properties of the Mobius function.  Specifically. $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {\mu(n)}{n^s}=\frac 1{\zeta(s)}$ Beyond that, what are you asking?

Comment: I''m not familiar with the first  thing you wrote, I'll check again

Comment: See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function)